# How open Foundation modal loaded dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using $.load() function to load html content. Inside this it, I listed card with button that on click should open a Foundation modal:

```
<button class="button button--modal-info button--modal-info--white user-area-card-modal-info" data-open="<?php echo 'user-area-card-' . $post_id . '-modal'; ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo 'user-area-card-' . $post_id . '-modal'; ?>" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">
        <i class="icon-info"></i>
</button>
```

---

```
<div class="modal modal--info tiny reveal" id="legend-modal" data-reveal>

<button class="close-button modal__close-btn" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>

<div class="modal__content">

    <p><?php echo get_field( '_m_legend_modal_description' ); ?></p>

</div>
```

Now I solved (in some way) my problem with this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.user-area-card-modal-info', function() {
    const open_id = $(this).data('open');
    new Foundation.Reveal($('#' + open_id)).open();
});
```

But often if I open and close modal, the latter close, but Overlay remains

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

- I included of modal out of the content generated dinamically
- Fetch text with attribute/hidden field and put it inside modal